# How can the parameters of the svr model be found from the fitrsvm function?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

the fitrsvm function in matlab contains parameters that are slightly different from the formulas and equations used in the literature .For example, the following parameters:
Alpha, Mu, Sigma, BoxConstraints, GapTolerance, Delta gradient and ... In articles, three important parameters are reported for the SVR model, including: C, gama, sigma, How can we find these three parameters from the model constructed by the fitrsvm function???